# Update multiple hyperlinks at once in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, updates

I have thousands of rows in my Microsoft Access DB and I would like to **update all values** in the column "Documento_Digitalizado". Values in this column are raw text that must be updated to be an hyperlink.

(The hyperlink direction has to be the text value of the cell)

This is my Access DB

[image]

This is the way to update them one by one.

[image]

Comment: Run a Find/Replace action or an UPDATE action SQL. A hyperlink field value is composed of three parts separated by # character. I prefer not to use hyperlink type field. Review https://ask.metafilter.com/148198/Batch-Update-Hyperlinks-in-Access-Table and https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-hyperlink-data-type

Answer (score 1):

First save a copy of your table just in case!
Create a query to up-date your original table Documento_Digitalizado column to show FULL file path if it does not already show it.
Then open your original table in design mode.
Change field type of Documento_Digitalizado from text to hyperlink
save, close.
To bulk edit hyperlink fields change date type from hyperlink to text, create and run query to amend file location, change field data type back to hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

I had to change drive letter in hyperlink.  Changed table column to long text from hyperlink and saved.  Exported to Excel. Dropped existing rows from table.  Bulk changed the drive letter in Excel.  Loaded to now empty table.  Changed table column to hyperlink.
300 rows of reference document links, 3 minutes to fix.